# Finding lowest test score and average of two high scores

Tags: python, average, display

I got everything else figured out in my homework but I am stuck on the last step which requires me to find the lowest test score then display the highest two test score's average and also show the lowest test score. I know I need to add an if/elif/else function beneath "def findAndReturnLowest" but I came out with errors. this is a screen shot of I should do it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1wgS.png)

this is my code

```
def main():
    score1 = 0.0
    score2 = 0.0
    score3 = 0.0

    score1 = getTestScore()
    score2 = getTestScore()
    score3 = getTestScore()

    calcAvgAndDisplayResults(score1, score2, score3)

def calcAvgAndDisplayResults(s1, s2, s3):
    lowest = 0.0
    average = 0.0
    lowest = findAndReturnLowest(s1, s2, s3)
def findAndReturnLowest(s1, s2, s3):


    average = (s1+s2+s3-lowest)/2
    print("Average = ", average)

def getTestScore():
    test = 0.0
    test=float(input("Enter a test score between 0 and 100: "))
    return test

# start of program
main()
```

Comment: so far you haven't done much in your code, seems like you just posted the prebuilt functions from the assignment. also your calculation for average does not look correct nor are you passing the variable `lowest` anywhere in that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `if`:

```
def findAndReturnLowest(s1, s2, s3):
    if s1 > s3 and s2 > s3:
        return s3

    else:
        return s2 if s1 > s2 else s1
```

Comment: @aws_apprentice True, totally missed that.

Comment: removed my downvote, but you can simplify those conditionals waaaaay more

Comment: is there supposed to be a supposed to be an elif function? Code isn't running this part. :(

Comment: @MosesMartinez you can take the second `if` out and combine it with the `else` to put into an `elif`.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple approach that should work, but there are plenty:

```
def main():
    score1 = 0.0
    score2 = 0.0
    score3 = 0.0

    score1 = getTestScore()
    score2 = getTestScore()
    score3 = getTestScore()

    calcAvgAndDisplayResults(score1, score2, score3)

def calcAvgAndDisplayResults(s1, s2, s3):
    lowest = findAndReturnLowest(s1, s2, s3)

def findAndReturnLowest(s1, s2, s3 ):
    lowest = min([int(x) for x in [s1,s2,s3]])
    average = (s1+s2+s3-lowest)/2
    print("Average = ", average)
    print("Lowest = ", lowest)

def getTestScore():
    test = 0.0
    test=float(input("Enter a test score between 0 and 100: "))
    return test

# start of program
main()
```

Comment: If you are going to use `sort`... why don't just use `min`?